# getting a type error when calling back data from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to get the data from a nested array but ended up getting the error type error cannot read property "value" of undefined, I don't know If I calling back in a wrong way but I end up getting the output in console along with the error

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var entries = [{name:"", address:"", month:"", year:""}];

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("homepage");
});

app.get("/addentry", function(req, res){
    res.render("add");
});

app.post("/add", function(req, res){
    var input = req.body;
    var newEntry = {name: input.name, address: input.address, month: input.month, year: input.year};
    entries.push(newEntry);
    res.redirect("/addentry");

});

app.post("/search", function(req, res){
    var search = req.body;
    for(var i = 0; i <= entries.length; i++){
            console.log(entries[i].name);
        }
        res.redirect("/addentry");
    
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server Started Successfully");
});
```

I end up getting this error always

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\app.js:29:36
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (C:\AllNodeProjects\globalledger\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  app.use(bodyParser.json()); after this line => app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));